# Cannot run Doclet class given by Oracle

Tags: java, javadoc, java-9, doclet

I want to experiment with Doclets (**JDK 9**), so I tried everything step by step given in this [link.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html) I have not add anything custom in `Example` class. It is exactly as Oracle gives it (I just declared the `import`s).

Oracle gives the command:

```
javadoc -doclet Example \
       -overviewfile overview.html \
       -sourcepath source-location \
       source-location/Example.java
```

Now when I run the given *javadoc* command, i get the following error:

> javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class Example

I tried some variations of the command since it seems to be a problem with directors but all of my tries have failed.

I place `Example.java` in my Desktop folder: `C:\Users\George\Desktop\`

So, in my command line I `cd C:\Users\George\Desktop\`. Then `javac Example.java` (in case it wants it compiled).

And then, i try all the following commands, getting the same error.

```
javadoc -doclet Example -overviewfile overview.html -sourcepath ./ ./Example.java
```

.

```
javadoc -doclet Example -overviewfile overview.html -sourcepath "C:\Users\George\Desktop\" "C:\Users\George\Desktop\Example.java"
```

(+without quotes)

`javadoc -doclet Example -overviewfile overview.html"C:\Users\George\Desktop\Example.java"`

I tried few other things found in SO, but again, nothing works. **What am i missing? Should not the given example work?**

Example class (in case you see something i do not):

```
public class Example implements Doclet {
    Reporter reporter;
    String overviewFile;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public Example() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Locale locale, Reporter reporter) {
        reporter.print(Kind.NOTE, "Doclet using locale: " + locale);
        this.reporter = reporter;
    }

    public void printElement(DocTrees trees, Element e) {
        DocCommentTree docCommentTree = trees.getDocCommentTree(e);
        if (docCommentTree != null) {
            System.out.println("Element (" + e.getKind() + ": " + e + ") has the following comments:");
            System.out.println("Entire body: " + docCommentTree.getFullBody());
            System.out.println("Block tags: " + docCommentTree.getBlockTags());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Example";
    }

    @Override
    public Set<? extends Option> getSupportedOptions() {
        Option[] options = { new Option() {
            private final List<String> someOption = Arrays.asList("-overviewfile", "--overview-file", "-o");

            @Override
            public int getArgumentCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "an option with aliases";
            }

            @Override
            public Option.Kind getKind() {
                return Option.Kind.STANDARD;
            }

            @Override
            public List<String> getNames() {
                return someOption;
            }

            @Override
            public String getParameters() {
                return "file";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean process(String opt, List<String> arguments) {
                overviewFile = arguments.get(0);
                return true;
            }
        } };
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(options));
    }

    @Override
    public SourceVersion getSupportedSourceVersion() {
        return SourceVersion.latest();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(DocletEnvironment docEnv) {
        reporter.print(Kind.NOTE, "overviewfile: " + overviewFile);
        // get the DocTrees utility class to access document comments
        DocTrees docTrees = docEnv.getDocTrees();

        // location of an element in the same directory as overview.html
        try {
            Element e = ElementFilter.typesIn(docEnv.getSpecifiedElements()).iterator().next();
            DocCommentTree docCommentTree = docTrees.getDocCommentTree(e, overviewFile);
            if (docCommentTree != null) {
                System.out.println("Overview html: " + docCommentTree.getFullBody());
            }
        } catch (IOException missing) {
            reporter.print(Kind.ERROR, "No overview.html found.");
        }

        for (TypeElement t : ElementFilter.typesIn(docEnv.getIncludedElements())) {
            System.out.println(t.getKind() + ":" + t);
            for (javax.lang.model.element.Element e : t.getEnclosedElements()) {
                printElement(docTrees, e);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled the class?

Comment: @JBNizet Oracle in the article, says nothing about compile. However, from another SO post i saw that, and yea, i did. Still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `javadoc --help` reveals the following option:

```
-docletpath <path>
              Specify where to find doclet class files
```

Use that option, and it should work fine (provided you compiled the Example class and it is indeed located in the directory passed as argument to this option).